# What to do with question that external cause caused the problem in it?

Tags: discussion

I mean this question in my case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26745108 I found that the solution that wasn't enough, had external problem that interferred with it and made it not enough. Editing in that problem to the question and answer it afterwards won't help future readers.

What should I do? Delete the question? I don't think my optimal path is to walk towards question ban. Is there any-other option?

Answer (score 1):

The presence of an external cause doesn't really change anything.

First, what to do with this new information:

- If its a completely different problem, and you could self-answer a new question, post it as such.
- If it just slightly changes your original problem, *edit*, and potentially self-answer. I don't see why doing so wouldn't help future readers

Now what to do with the old:

- You can always leave it be, its at 0 score and isn't hurting you. Unfortunately, its sounds like its impossible to give the correct answer due to this external factor
- Delete it, which since it is 0 score, won't hurt you much if at all question-ban wise.

Comment: My problem is that I tested something and I sent the data to the performance profiler every 10ms instead once program is finished. It's really small bug, it will hurt me to ask this question and answer it. (question-ban guaranteed) I guess I will just leave it be, thanks.